# How do I make refspec style github commits urls?

Tags: url, github

When referring to commit history on github, you can use some versions of a git refspec, e g:

```
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/commits/         = default branch
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/commits/gh-pages = gh-pages branch or tag
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/commits/7aafe0de9edf3f67b7f73e9ebab47ff9f2309415
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/commits/?author=duopixel
```

When using the compare feature, you can use [any type of git respec just as easily](https://speakerdeck.com/holman/git-and-github-secrets#106), e g:

```
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/compare/gh-pages~1...gh-pages
https://github.com/johan/kilobyte-svg-challenge/compare/gh-pages@{1.month.ago}...gh-pages
```

**Are there similar provisions for making time/count-relative commits urls, and if so, what does the url syntax look like?**

If this kind of tribal knowledge is documented anywhere on their help pages, I have yet to find it. Github's urls are at the same time among the best designed ones on the web and the worst (publicly?) documented, as best I can tell.